# Verify that input text length is greater than 0 and is also numeric in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to figure out why this code below isn't working:

```
  if ($('#sets').val().length  >  0  &&
      $.isNumeric(('#sets').val())   &&
      $('#reps').val().length  >  0  &&
      $.isNumeric(('#reps').val())   ){
    $("#exercises_submit").prop("disabled", false);
  }
  else {
    $("#exercises_submit").prop("disabled", true);
  }
```

It worked just fine prior to adding in the .isNumeric validations (when it just checked for length) but I'd also like it verify the user is inputting integers as well.

Comment: Both times, you are missing a `$` before the selector : `$.isNumeric($('#reps').val())`

Comment: .isNumeric returns False for empty string so you shouldn't need the extra test for length http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isnumeric/

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, first time I've ever used that function. Not sure why I'm being downvoted for it, however...

Comment: one reason for downvotes is most likely that you aren't even bothering to check your browser console for errors that would certainly be thrown from code shown. You should at least be doing rudimentary troubleshooting before asking questions

Comment: Which I did.. "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" didn't help me fix the error.. jeez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing `$` typos aside, you can really clean up your code to be more declarative and intuitive. Consider this:

```
var sets = $('#sets').val(),
    reps = $('#reps').val();

function numHasValue (num) {
    return num && $.isNumeric(num) 
} 

$("#exercises_submit").prop("disabled", (numHasValue(sets) && numHasValue(reps)) );
```

Comment: This method is a lot better than what I had, however if (numHasValue(sets) && numHasValue(reps)) is true, then the button is disabled, rather than enabled

Comment: Ah, just realized I can just do !(numHasValue(sets) && numHasValue(reps)) to get the reverse and it works great. Thank you for your help!